# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (error 2002)

Tags: mysql, sockets, mysql-error-2002

I know this is a question many times asked, but I can't seem to find any solution out of the other topics.

what I've tried:

- reinstalling mysql-server (so not the client)
- `chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`
- checked out my.cnf where everything seems correct
- changed bind-address to localhost
- at a certain point it seemed I had no socket file and

  `sudo find / -type s | grep mysqld.sock` doesn't give any result.

  ---

***Edit***

I now entered `mysql_config --socket` and it seems there is a socket file in place now at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

also checked `apparmor_status` which gave following result:

```
apparmor module is loaded.
14 profiles are loaded.
14 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/mysqld
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
0 profiles are in complain mode.
3 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
3 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
   /sbin/dhclient (1089) 
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (1415) 
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (16608)
```

After all this `/etc/init.d/mysql start` still fails

settings in my.cnf

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

---

I checked out `/var/log/error.log` and when I try `# /etc/init.d/mysql start` following reports show up from the log:

```
150528 22:58:19 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150528 22:58:19 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150528 22:58:19 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 14608 ...
150528 22:58:19 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150528 22:58:19 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150528 22:58:19 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
150528 22:58:19 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
150528 22:58:19 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150528 22:58:19 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150528 22:58:19 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150528 22:58:19 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150528 22:58:19 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150528 22:58:19 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150528 22:58:19 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150528 22:58:19  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150528 22:58:20 InnoDB: 5.5.43 started; log sequence number 140421610
150528 22:58:20 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): 'localhost'; port: 3306
150528 22:58:20 [Note]   - 'localhost' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
150528 22:58:20 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
150528 22:58:20 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
150528 22:58:20 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
150528 22:58:20 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Can someone help me out how to get it fixed without loosing my db's

Comment: Are you using the directory `/mysql/data/dir` as a data directory? Have you also updated your `my.cnf` file accordingly? By default MySQL will look in `/var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: I see you are using Ubuntu, so check also if `apparmor` is in enforce mode for MySQL (the command is `apparmor_status`).

Comment: The dir was a format, it's real location is indeed `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: You need to initialize mysql data directory by running either `mysql_install_db` or `mysql_secure_installation`. Then you can start `mysqld`.

Comment: When I run `mysql_secure_installation` I need to enter the root password, after that it gives the same error --> no socket file. So I ran `mysql_install_db` and did as the cmd suggested, so I was able to enter mysql and `show tables` also worked, but selecting from these tables gives following error `ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './mysql/user.frm' (errno: 13)`

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql install is hosed:

```
150528 22:58:20 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
```

It's not starting up in the first place, hence not having a socket file. You're missing data from the internal/core `mysql` database, which is a very bad sign.

Comment: I don't believe his installation is hosed. I think he didn't initialize the data directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't initialized the data directory, now is the time to initialize it before starting `mysqld`.

You can run either of these 2 scripts provided by mysql. From your shell prompt run them as:

```
# mysql_secure_installation
```

or

```
# mysql_install_db --user=mysql \
         --basedir=<path to mysql install dir> \
         --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/data
```

`mysql_install_db` will invoke `mysqld` with `--bootstrap` and `--skip-grant-tables` options.

Comment: now it seems that I don't have a socket file after all. Although when i run `mysql_config --socket` it saids it's there, but when I check the folder there's nothing in it. And so the error stays the same

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_install_db` cmd did the trick. I have a socket again and I"m now able to login to mysql again. Thx